# Why dosen't this css file work

Tags: html, css, mime-types

I was trying to host my css files on an cloud storage service but when I linked it to my website it was not executed,
so i created an small css which just changes background but yet it doesn't works.
It seems there is some problem with its server will you please tell me what could be the problem and how to use it as css
link of css file http://copy.com/Kgs8EaMF71Qa7zqo/style.css
HTML Code

```
<link href="http://copy.com/Kgs8EaMF71Qa7zqo/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to security reasons MIME type of files hosted on copy.com is served as `text/plain`
So an normal link like of CSS file from copy.com will not work.

But if you still want to host your css files on this cloud storage service you can by adding `?download=1` after your link so you html should be like

```
<link href="http://copy.com/Kgs8EaMF71Qa7zqo/style.css?download=1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

there are several other cloud service like [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com),[Google Drive](http://drive.google.com) where you can host your external CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Incorrect_MIME_Type_for_CSS_Files

At least Gecko has a security feature for this: All stylesheets *not from the same origin* must be served with `text/css`.

In fact, you're file is served as `text/plain`, so the rules in it are ignored.

Comment: how to check that the file is served as **text/plain**

Comment: open Firebug (if not installed, get it as an addon). Reload the page and inspect the "Response Headers" in the network section.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it may be due to MIME type, you uploaded assuming it will work as css file but its actual MIME type will be plain type **text/plain** but required MIME type to make it work as css file is **text/css**

So It Wont work.

Answer (score 0):

This file worked perfectly for me.
here is the html code with the output.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://copy.com/Kgs8EaMF71Qa7zqo/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: It works on other browsers but have issues with **Mozilla Firefox**